# Finding the Boundary Conditions for a Laplace's Equation in Polar Coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, harmonic-functions

I have solved Laplace's equation in Polar Coordinates for the scalar electric potential in a circle of radius R and have the solution 
$$
\phi(r,\varphi) = \phi_{0} + \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}r^{k_{\varphi}}\left(A_{k}\sin(k\varphi)+B_k\cos(k\varphi)\right)
$$

Where $k_{\varphi}$ is a constant times k.

Now the boundary condition that I have is $\vec{n}\cdot\vec{J}=0$ where n is the normal to the surface, and $\vec{J}$ is the current density. This can be written as 
$$
\vec{n}\cdot \vec{\nabla}\phi=-\vec{n}\cdot\frac{\partial\vec{A}}{\partial t}
$$
Since the system is quasi-static the magnetic vector potential, A, can be separated into a spacial and time component written as $\vec{A}(\vec{s},t)= \vec{A}(s)f(t)$ for an arbitrary function of time. The magnetic vector potential is known and is:
$$
\vec{A}= \frac x{r^2}\hat{\varphi}
$$
Where x is just a constant.

My attempt was to write the Boundary condition as
$$
\vec{n}\cdot \left( 
\begin{matrix} 
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial r} \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{r\partial \varphi } 
\end{matrix} \right) = =\vec{n}\cdot \left( 
\begin{matrix} 
0\\
\frac{x}{r^2} 
\end{matrix} \right)\cdot \dot{f}(t)
$$
What I am not sure about is what is the normal vector to a circle of radius R? or if my approach is correct?

Thank you.

Comment: The normal vector to the circle is $(R cos \phi , R sin \phi)$

Comment: @Semsem From the context, $\vec n$ is a **unit** normal vector, which is $(\cos \varphi, \sin\varphi)$.

Comment: yes it is ok !!

Answer (score 1):

Taking full gradient and then multiplying by $\vec n$ is doing too much. The outward normal derivative at the boundary of the circle is simply the partial derivative with respect to $r$. So, 
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} =  -\vec{n}\cdot\frac{\partial\vec{A}}{\partial t}
\tag{1}$$ 
Next, your formula for $\vec A$ says that this vector is a multiple of $\hat \varphi$, which I understand to be a unit tangent vector. If so, then the time derivative of $\vec A$ is tangent to the circle, too. Consequently, the right hand side of (1) is zero.

So, it appears that $\phi$ must be a harmonic function with zero normal derivative; the only such functions are the constant ones.

---

An aside: using both $\phi$ and $\varphi$ in the same computation is usually a bad idea.